# How check in python, cmake or c++ if ArcGIS license is valid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c++, license

I'm trying to programmatically check if the ArcGIS license is valid.  I want to query the license validity either in cmake or in c++.  There are also python scripts associated with cmake.  I'd handle the license info in two different possible ways.  I tried looking for how to query the license validity, but can't find anything online.  I don't want to check it as an administrator.  I have code that uses ArcGIS that we want to query/handle that info.

1. In cmake I'd take this info and set some definitions I can use later to not run tests when the license isn't valid.  or,
2. In the c++ code, if I could query the license status, I could use that info to not run tests.

I did see this link for [CheckProduct](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/checkproduct.htm), but it doesn't identify what language they are showing the example in (not c++).  I'm not sure if CheckProduct would work for c++, python, or cmake.

Comment: CheckProduct you found is python, or more specifically inside the arcpy package of ArcGIS. What is your workflow? To run a python script against ArcGIS? If so, you dont need to worry about c++. You can do the logic flows entirely inside your py script checking to see if you have a license available

Comment: The python scripting is part of our cmake.  I'm not sure how CheckProduct works with ArcGIS.  If ArcGIS license was valid at build time, would CheckProduct work.  Is arc py package something we can use without telling the python script where we're getting CheckProduct from?  Would CheckProduct work if we had ArcGIS installed but the license was out of date?

Comment: To run anything arcpy you need to run the script on the same machine as ArcMap, or ArcGIS Server, etc. (I've never used cmake, so I dont know what that does). Typically you only need to CheckProduct if you have multiple license levels and want to be 'smart' about what one you run against.  Simply doing an `import arcpy` should fail if you arent licensed. I'd read the [first few paragraphs heres](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/access-to-licensing-and-extensions.htm). It may clear up if you even need to do this check in your workflow

Comment: It sounds like my team wants to do it during runtime (c++) now instead of build-time (python). If we have our url to the server, is there a command I can use to check if it's valid/available?  I'm reading that pinging a server doesn't work to check if it's available/valid alone and that we need to make a request that only the server would be able to answer if it was available.

Comment: You can check ArcGIS licensing at any time, but it only counts at runtime.

Comment: It turns out that ArcGIS always returns success, whether I give it a good url or not.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to do a htpp get request with json and then parse the json response for error.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can check it using arcpy extension. Here is code. You can also check the extension that are available in ArcGIS

```
import arcpy

print arcpy.ProductInfo()

## Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst Extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give a general answer, since most of it isn't code I can share.

To check the server is available, first I set up the uri to the server:

```
String uri = /*server info/* +  String("/address/address/.../Server?f=json");
```

Notice the ?f=json above, that will give us a json result when we look for it.

Then I use this to do the GET http request.

I call code that parses the json result, looking for "error" (has value).

I get the "error/code" and "error/message" from that.

This is a runtime c++ check. (not cmake/python)